# Max idle connections in YugabyteDB YCQL?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm using golang with YugabyteDB YCQL for my application. I'm also familiar with YSQL (PostgreSQL). In YSQL api, we can configure max idle connection. Is there a way to configure max idle connection for YCQL as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "max idle connections", but "max connections" (https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#ysql-max-connections).

Note that YCQL connections are multiplexing, you can have many queries running concurrently, therefore you may only need 2-4 maximum connections per client.

Even the modern Java driver doesn't resize connection pools anymore. There's a pool size for local/remote nodes (as designated by the load balancing policy) and each connection can handle a max number of concurrent requests per connection. The pool sizes are set to 1 for local, 1 for remote and max connections are set to 1024.

Example: In an application, we set `NumConns` to 2 and we're doing over 300 queries per second without issue.